# Add a hover text on a salesforce custom object tab

Tags: custom-object, tab, object, salesforce-classic

I have a Custom object which has a tab in Salesforce Classic Is there any way to add a description text/ hover text on the tab?

Answer (score 0):

We can't really add help text on hover but you can choose a custom link to use as the introductory splash page when users initially click the tab.

So here you can give details about the tab.

[Create a Custom Object Tab](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_custom_object_tabs.htm&type=5)